# how to print y-axis large values

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi i am plotting line graph and my code is this but i am not sure how y axis is plotting as i have very large value 18965544, 45668787, but how y axis plotting values as values like 1 2 3

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 16})
L=[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H]
New=[18965544, 45668787, 46768733, 865533, 32586879, 996665544, 53544222,97775644]  
Old= [23455, 0,0,0,0, 996665544, 65645, 654535]
plt.plot(FLMAUB) 
plt.plot(RandomFL)
plt.legend(['new', 'old'], loc='upper right')
plt.xticks(x1, L, rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.plot(New, Old)
plt.title('New Vs Old')
plt.xlabel('Names')
plt.ylabel('Cost')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe you should try the scientific notations format: plt.ticklabel_format(axis="y", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0))

Comment: but if 49000000 is the highest value its not good to use this value in scilimits=(0,49000000) what would be the best option

Comment: (0,0) if I am sure includes all numbers, you don't need to input anything extra it will adapt to your numbers

Answer (score 0):

I thought of some possibilities, you could try these:

- **Using a linear space with [`numpy.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)**

```
# With this method you can create an evenly spaced range of values
# given a start, the end and how many numbers you want in this interval

from numpy import linspace
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# You could use 'min()' and 'max()' for the range of your data array
plt.yticks(linspace('min_value', 'max_value', 'how_many_samples'))

# Something like
plt.linspace(18965544, 45668787, 12)
```

- **Using another scale from [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale.html)**

```
# You can unpack the subplots tuple as conventioned
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_yscale('log')  # For an example, you can use Logarithmic scale
```

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.plot(New,Old)
plt.ticklabel_format(axis="both", style="scientific", scilimits=(0,0))
```

It will give you this image. You have the y and x axes from 0-1.0 but they are multiplied by $1x10^9$.
[image]